# jQuery sortable, how I can get the id of the dragged element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Having this code in jQuery 2.1.4 + jQuery UI 1.11.4, how I can get the id of the dragged element?

```
$( "#form" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        //I WANNA GET DRAGGED ITEM ID HERE
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Please check example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/u8r3b2nw/1/

PD: I already searched in here, but nothing works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're cloning the dragged element and `id` must by unique, it gets removed from the clone. If can you use other attribute, like for example `data-id`, you should be able to easily access with `ui.item.attr('data-id')`.

But I got `id` when using [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event, but it's only triggered during dragging, not sorting.

```
$( "#form" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.attr('id'));
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Another workaround is to move it to  `draggable`

```
$( ".item" ).draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
  cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 20, left: 56 },
  connectToSortable: '#form',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Hopefully one of those will work for you.

Comment: Great! Now, how can I get the new item position (index) in this receive function?

Comment: No luck so far, looks like you can get  `ui.position`, but not the `ui.item.index()` - not the correct one at least. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems the id's are being stripped when the item is dropped in the table. I've found a workaround but it's pretty messy. I hope somebody else can come up with a better solution for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/u8r3b2nw/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Store the id in this scope
    var id;

    $(".item").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 20,
            left: 56
        },
        connectToSortable: '#form',

        // On drag start store the element's id.
        start: function () {
            id = this.id;
        }
    });

    $("#form").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        update: function(event, ui) {

            // If the item doesn't have an id add it from the stored value.
            // Length check makes sure it isn't overwritten.

            if (!ui.item[0].id.length) {
                ui.item[0].id = id;
            }

            // Alert the id of the sorted element
            alert(ui.item[0].id);

        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
```